# How to call block in phtml magento 1.9.*

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to make shipping -> "Pickup in store". But in shipping model we can't add [image]

how can we do it in payment?
I have Block/Stores.php and template shipment/stores.phtml, I want to add this template to available.phtml in this place

[image]

I succesfuly overrided the onepage\shipping_method\available.phtml

[image]
and added [image] in my overrided available.phtml. But my stores.phtml doesn't joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not add .phtml in template call you should use

```
<block type="shipment/stores" name="stores" template="shipment/stores.phtml"/>
```

or you can call directly block code inside phtml at the place of  **$this->getChildHtml('stores')**.

```
<?php echo $this->getlayout()->createBlock('shipment/stores')->setTemplate('shipment/stores.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: If I use it, the block "3 delivery options" is not opened in the checkout, I click the "Continue" button in the "2 sending information", but nothing happens.

Comment: check in console is there any js error ?

Comment: This error is coming because magento is not getting block shipment/stores

Comment: can you share etc/config.xml file ?

Comment: did you create block file Tsymbal_Shipment_Block_Stores ? and also did you check with flush cache ?

Comment: can you accept my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('your/block')
    ->setTemplate('your/phtmlfile.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Comment: If I use it, the block "3 delivery options" is not opened in the checkout, I click the "Continue" button in the "2 sending information", but nothing happens.